# IMG height set to 60% but parent DIV still stretches to 100%

Tags: html, css, image, height

In our ecommerce project all photos are squares. So some products have a lot of whitespace on top and bottom. I wan't to 'cut' that space without editing the photos (thousands). I almost achieved my goal. But parent DIV stretches to basic 100% of the IMG.

```css
.container {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0 40px;
}

.main-header {
 height: 80px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: grey;
}

.product {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.media {
 flex: 1;
 background-color: grey;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

.landscape {
 object-fit: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 60%;
}

.purchase {
 width: 160px;
 background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <header class="main-header">
   
  </header>
  
  <content class="product">
   
   <div class="media">
    <img class="landscape" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0286/1214/products/Trance-3-Color-B-Neon-Green.jpg">
   </div>
   
   <div class="purchase">
    
   </div>
  
  </content>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove `height: 60%` from your image (which doesn't affect your image, but the `.media`'s div height, since that div has no height set to it.). Now the container div resizes depending on the image's size (or the content of the other '.purchase' div in the flex-container, if that has more height).

Hope it helps, since I am really just guessing what you are trying to do here.

```css
.container {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0 40px;
}

.main-header {
 height: 80px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: grey;
}

.product {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.media {
 flex: 1;
 background-color: grey;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

.landscape {
 object-fit: cover;
 width: 100%;
}

.purchase {
 width: 160px;
 background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <header class="main-header">
   
  </header>
  
  <content class="product">
   
   <div class="media">
    <img class="landscape" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0286/1214/products/Trance-3-Color-B-Neon-Green.jpg">
   </div>
   
   <div class="purchase">
    
   </div>
  
  </content>
 </div>
```

Comment: First of all – thx for ur time and answer! I will try to explain ;) I have photos os bicycles. They all are 2000x2000px. But they have a lot of white space on top and bottom from the actual bicycle view. So i'm trying to make this photos shorter without cropping them (there are thousands of them) in graphic redactor.

In my version I 'cropped' the image with css, but it doesn't effect the container. I'm trying to fix it. And I can't use the photos as background imgs.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `height:60%;` from `.landscape` and instead set a fixed height for both `.media` and `.landscape` in pixels.

```css
.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.main-header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.media {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}

.landscape {
  object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

.purchase {
  width: 160px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="main-header">
      
    </header>
    
    <content class="product">
      
      <div class="media">
        <img class="landscape" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0286/1214/products/Trance-3-Color-B-Neon-Green.jpg">
      </div>
      
      <div class="purchase">
        
      </div>
    
    </content>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I can't use pixels. I have images with aspect ratio 1:1, and I wanna view them with aspect ratio (for example) 16:9. But they should be responsive and can't be used as background images, only with <img> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I've found a solution by using the Javascript. Hope I will find some day pure CSS/HTML solution.

```js
window.onload   = resizer;
window.onresize = resizer;
function resizer() {
 var div = document.getElementById('media');
 div.style.height = (div.offsetWidth / 1.5) + 'px';
};
```

```css
div {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0 40px;
}

.main-header {
 height: 80px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: grey;
}

.product {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row nowrap;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#media {
 flex: 1;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-right: 20px;
 background-color: grey;
}

#media > img {
 object-fit: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.purchase {
 width: 360px;
 background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <title>Hello world!</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <header class="main-header">
   
  </header>
  
  <content class="product">
   
   <div id="media">
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0286/1214/products/Trance-3-Color-B-Neon-Green.jpg">
   </div>
   
   <div class="purchase">
    
   </div>
  
  </content>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```